# In reverse-history-search in zsh, is there a maximum # of items it will go back?

Tags: zsh, readline

I use control-r interactive reverse history search in zsh all day long. Just now I tried to find something I haven't used in quite some time, and it wasn't there. But when I grepped my .zsh_history file, it was there.

Is there a maximum # of history entries reverse search will search? Can I configure this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure (in your `.zshrc`) how long the history per session and the stored one is:

```
HISTSIZE=5000 # session history size
SAVEHIST=1000 # saved history
HISTFILE=~/.zshistory # history file
```

That is what is searched by zsh, I am not aware of a limit that `reverse-history-search` uses.

You might want to check on the `zsh-param(1)` man page.

Comment: that was it! my histsize was smaller than my savehist, and that does indeed seem to be the limit that reverse-interactive-search will search (make sense). https://github.com/jjb/dotfiles/commit/3f46baacfa34a86f122cf933d25402719361c8ab

Answer (score 1):

In-memory history may not contain entries that are in the history file (if the file size limit is larger than the in-memory limit) and the history file may not contain entries that are in memory (until they're written - either explicitly or when the shell exits - subject to size limits set by environment variables). There is no other limit on `reverse-history-search`.

This is true in Bash and I believe the Z shell is similar.